# ASP.NET MVC3 Raw Sql Update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rawsql

I'm sure I'm doing a simple mistake. I try to run raw Update statement in my ASP.NET MVC3 project.

```
if (Request["btApprove"] == (string)ViewBag._Approve)
{
    query = "UPDATE Proposals SET "
          + " TypeID=" + Request["ProposalTypes"]
          + " RejectionTypeID=" + Request["RejectionTypes"]
          + " Title='" + Request["taProposalTitle"] + "'"
          + " Explanation='" + Request["taProposalDescription"] + "'"
          + " RejectionCause='" + Request["taRejectionCause"] + "'"
          + " WHERE ID=" + Request["txProposalNo"] + " ";
     db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
}
```

The lines above return the error: "Incorrect syntax near 'RejectionTypeID'." I debug the project but the query seems right.

```
"UPDATE Proposals SET  TypeID=1 RejectionTypeID=1 Title='SomeText' Explanation='Some Longer Text' RejectionCause='' WHERE ID=1 "
```

**RejectionTypeID** is a foreign key, depends on **ID** of the table **RejectionTypes** and they are of type **int**, telling in case there's a violation. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after each variable set add "," (comma).

Comment: I feel really bad :) Thank you for quick response. Accepting in 8 minutes.